# Async JavaScript in production environment only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I'm trying to get my JavaScript (Angular app) to load asynchronously so that the page can render a loading image while the browser downloads the JavaScript later.  In production, this works just fine, but not in development, because Sprockets hasn't concatinated all of the files yet.

I'm using the following in my HAML file:

```
= javascript_include_tag "mio", :async => true
```

which is working as intended in production:

```
<script async="async" src="/assets/mio.js"></script>
```

However, in development the files are all separate, and execute out of order.  For example, my Angular Quote Form Controller is executing before Angular has finished loading:

```
<script async="async" src="/assets/angular.js?body=1"></script>
<script async="async" src="/assets/mio.js?body=1"></script>
<script async="async" src="/assets/mio-ng/controllers/quote_form.js?body=1"></script>
```

So the question is, can `javascript_include_tag` ignore the `async` flag when in development, but not in production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to rig this up to work, but I feel it is not the best solution:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application", :async => Rails.env == "production"
```

Comment: It's not that bad I guess!

Comment: `Rails.env.production?` is more idiomatic